# Sort a class array by a string attribute in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I need to alphabetically sort an array `User[] contactList` (composed by instances of a custom class `User`) by a built-in String attribute. I mean, for example, my class user is:

```
public class User{
    String firstName;
    
    public User(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName; 
    }
}
```

If my array `contactList` is composed by the following items:

> contactList[0] has firstName = "Maria"
>
> contactList[1] has firstName = "Andrew"
>
> contactList[2] has firstName = "Joey"

I want to sort it alphabetically by their `firstName` and thus, the result should be:

> sortedList[0] should have firstName = "Andrew"
>
> sortedList[1] should have firstName = "Joey"
>
> sortedList[2] should have firstName = "Maria"

How could I achieve that in Java (Android)?

**Edit 1:** I cannot use *lambda expressions* in my project because I am using Java 7 in Android Studio.

**Edit 2:** I also cannot modify the `User` class. I simplified it in this question, but that class is a built-in class of an API.

Comment: *"How could I achieve that in Java (Android)?"* By doing research, searching here on SO, reviewing the JavaDoc of the JDK, and taking a stab at it. *If* you do all that and run into a *specific* problem, post a question with your code and a description of that specific problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Aha. But, in fact, THIS is a specific problem. I simplified it A LOT in order to make it straightforward. I have made previous research and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Oh pull the other one, it has legs on. You can't find anything on the entire web about how to sort an array in Java? Nonsense.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449766/java-sorting-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-property-object-not-allowed-to-use-co, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/using-comparator-to-make-custom-sort, and probably a dozen others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java 8 use a lambda expression and the Arrays sort function:

```
Users[] someUsers = {user1, user2, user3};
Arrays.sort(someUsers, (a,b) -> a.firstName.compareTo(b.firstName));
```

For previous versions use a Collection Comparator:

```
Users[] someUsers = {user1, user2, user3};
List<Users> userList = new ArrayList<Users>(Arrays.asList(someUsers));
Comparator<Users> comparator = new Comparator<Users>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Users left, Users right) {
        return left.firstName.compareTo(right.firstName);
    }
};
Collections.sort(userList, comparator);
```

Comment: It seems that I cannot use lambda expression because I am not using Java 8 in my Android Studio project (lambda expressions are not supported at this language level)... Is there anther way to achieve it?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include using a Comparator for older versions of Java

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.sort` on an array to sort it. However, that method has no way of knowing how to sort `User`s. To make that happen, you need to implement the `Comparable` interface and then have the `compareTo` method delegate the comparison to the `firstName` field:

```
public static class User implements Comparable<User>{
  String firstName;
  public User(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName; 
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(User o) {
    return firstName.compareTo(o.firstName);
  }
}
```

Now you can simply sort the array using `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is that I cannot update the User class because it is a built-in class of an API :(